# Delete an item of a ListView and of Base SQL with a deletebutton

Tags: android, sql, listview

I'm trying to build an application : We can add a player in a listView (player which is also stocked in a SQL base) and I would like to add a button just next each player name to edit or delete it (to create an AlertDialog whith two choices). For the moment, I just want to delete the item of the ListView and of the SQL Base, so I tried and changed a little bit my code but now, my List has disapeared ! And I don't find the problem

This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button AddPlayer=null;
EditText edittextplayer = null;
ArrayList<Player> Players = new ArrayList<Player>();
ListView playerListView;
DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   AddPlayer=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   edittextplayer=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextplayer);
   playerListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
   dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
   AddPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Player player = new Player(dbHandler.getPlayerCount(), String.valueOf(edittextplayer.getText()));
           if(!playerExists(player)){
               dbHandler.createPlayer(player);
               Players.add(player);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(edittextplayer.getText()) + " has been added to your Players!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               return;
           }
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(edittextplayer.getText()) + " already exists. Please use a different name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }



   });

   edittextplayer.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


       }
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           AddPlayer.setEnabled(String.valueOf(edittextplayer.getText()).trim().length() > 0);

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       }
   });
   if (dbHandler.getPlayerCount() != 0)
       Players.addAll(dbHandler.getAllPlayer());

   populateList();







}
private boolean playerExists(Player player) {
    String name = player.getName();
    int playerCount = Players.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++) {
        if (name.compareToIgnoreCase(Players.get(i).getName()) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void populateList() {
    ArrayAdapter<Player> adapter = new PlayerListAdapter(Players);
    playerListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class PlayerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
    ArrayList<Player> list = new ArrayList<Player>();

    private PlayerListAdapter(ArrayList<Player> list) {
        super (MainActivity.this, R.layout.listviewitem);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertview;
        if (view == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewitem, parent, false);
        }




        Player currentPlayer = Players.get(position);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewplayer);
        name.setText(currentPlayer.getName());

        ImageButton deleteplayer = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Imagebuttoneditcontact);
        deleteplayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                list.remove(position); //or some other task
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });










        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

This is the class DataBaseHandler

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PlayerManager",
        TABLE_PLAYER = "players",
        KEY_ID = "id",
        KEY_NAME = "name";




public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PLAYER + "("+KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT)");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLAYER);

    onCreate(db);

}
public void createPlayer(Player player) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, player.getName());


    db.insert(TABLE_PLAYER, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public Player getPlayer(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PLAYER, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null );

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Player player = new Player(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1));
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return player;
}
public void deleteContact(Player player) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_PLAYER, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(player.getId()) });
    db.close();
}
public int getPlayerCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PLAYER, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    return count;
}

public int updatePlayer(Player player) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, player.getName());


    int rowsAffected = db.update(TABLE_PLAYER, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(player.getId()) });
    db.close();

    return rowsAffected;
}

public List<Player> getAllPlayer() {
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PLAYER, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            players.add(new Player(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1)));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return players;
}
```

}

And this is the clas Player :

```
public class Player {
protected String name;
private int id;

public Player(int id, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Player{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}';
}
```

}

Thank you very much for your help because I'm quite stuck and I try a lot of things but nothing works ! it's probably a stupid mistake.. If you also tell me how delete the player from my DatabaseHandler it would be Great !!
Bye

Comment: Up because I'm really stuck ^^